# Run nginx and node js in same container

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, nginx

Hi I am trying to run node js and nginx as a proxy server. I can make them work if they are both in different container running simultaneously. But when trying to pack and run them both in same container it fails somehow.

Here is the dockerfile I am using to build that.

```
FROM nginx
#install node 14.19.1
RUN apt update
RUN apt install wget -y
RUN apt install xz-utils -y
RUN wget https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.19.1/node-v14.19.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
RUN tar -xvf node-v14.19.1-linux-x64.tar.xz
RUN cp -r node-v14.19.1-linux-x64/bin /usr/
RUN cp -r node-v14.19.1-linux-x64/include /usr/
RUN cp -r node-v14.19.1-linux-x64/lib /usr/
RUN cp -r node-v14.19.1-linux-x64/share /usr/
RUN export PATH=/usr/node-v14.19.1-linux-x64/bin:$PATH
#nginx conf  
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
#run node js server
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

And this one is using node js image

```
FROM node:14.19.1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
#install and configure nginx
RUN apt update
RUN apt install nginx -y
#COPY myserver.config /etc/nginx/sites-available
#RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myserver.config /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
#RUN nginx -t 
#RUN service nginx restart
#RUN ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
#install and run node server
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

This is the nginx.conf file that I am trying to run nginx through I know the localhost:3000 does not seem working. Can you please suggest me an alternative to make this work. Thanks

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name pnext;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass 0.0.0.0:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        # location /overview {
        #     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$request_uri;
        #     proxy_redirect off;
        # }
    }
}
```

Comment: Running two processes in one container usually isn't recommended.  You say you have a working setup with two separate containers, which would be a best practice; can you keep using that existing setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes that is the optimal approach, but as of now we are running these container in an EC2 environment where we have all the access to underlying hardware and architecture. But now we are planning to migrate this thing to ECS running on far-gate. Running two different container and the one running node js will be auto scaled by AWS then we would be required to setup two load balancer one in front of nginx and other in front of node js service. I just want to remove at least one load balancer layer from the infrastructure. If you have any solution to this one without running in same

Comment: container please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nginx as a sidecar in ECS container if you are using ECS as you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just change your CMD line to the following:

```
CMD nginx -g 'pid /tmp/nginx.pid;' & node server.js
```